# How to get an image from PhotoLibrary as attachment

Tags: iphone

I want to obtain image with metadata from photolibrary as an attachment for MFMailComposer. I did it by using the Image Picker to select the image from photolibrary.

Is there any way to obtain the image from PhotoLibrary in iphone without using the Image Picker???

Comment: No.  (Maybe in jailbroken iphones). By the way what is wrong with image picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSAssetLibrary. Here is a basic tutorial:

http://www.fiveminutes.eu/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/

Comment: Your suggestion was helpful. I used NSAssestLibrary url to reference the image saved to photo album and i was able to attach the image in MFMail Composer also... Thanks for your help...

Comment: @user887372: please consider accepting this answer as correct if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

first fetch the photo from photolibrary
[link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/)

then send that `UIImage` using `MFMailComposerViewController`

[link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/73130-mfmailcomposer-picture-attachment-camera.html)